# Line break in React textarea

Tags: reactjs

How to implement line break in Textarea field in React. For example, I want to press "Enter" and track the press.

Doesn't work in this case

```
const onChangeTextarea = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        console.log('Enter')
    }
};
```

Comment: **Solution**: I need to use the onKeyDown handler to track the Enter press and I used onChange which didn't work in my cases

Answer (score 0):

**Detect when the Enter key is pressed in React.js**

To detect when the Enter key is pressed in React.js:

1. Add a `keydown` event listener to the `document` element.
2. When the user presses a key, check if the key is `Enter`.
3. Invoke a function or run some logic if the pressed key is `Enter`.

   ```
   import {useEffect} from 'react';

   const App = () => {
       const myFunction = () => {
       // your logic here
       console.log('pressed Enter ✅');
   };

   useEffect(() => {
      const keyDownHandler = event => {
        console.log('User pressed: ', event.key);

        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault();

        // ️ your logic here
        myFunction();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler);

   return () => {
     document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler);
   };
   }, []);

   return (
     <div>
       <h2>Hello world</h2>
     </div>
    );
   };

   export default App;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work because I'll be tracking all the Enter hits by the user. And it is necessary for me only on pressing in Textarea. I found a solution, I need to use the onKeyDown handler